# How to select suitable kernel for Gaussian Processes (GP)?

Tags: math, machine-learning

I know that in GP, different from the SVM, kernel is to measure the similarity between one point and a given point. However, is there a general guideline for kernel selection? Or is there any material which introduce the characteristics of popular kernels (like the squared exponential kernel)?

By the way, Dr. Lin (author of LIBSVM toolbox) explained why the RBF kernel is probably the first choice for the SVM, so could anyone please tell me why the SE kernel is so popular in GP?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have touched upon a few common questions people have about Gaussian Processes. I'll try my best to answer them:

**Model Selection:** Model selection is an important and non-trivial aspect of GPs. It is usually left up to the user as they tend to be application specific. This can be a problem though as the user may not be a GP kernel guru and if we choose a poor model for our data then we inevitably get poor predictive performance. Some attempts have been made in this regard though. If you read chapter 5.2 of [GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/) it talks about bayesian model selection which should help you.

**Useful Kernels:** There is a lot of useful literature on kernels and when to use them. However if you know a few primitive kernels and learn the basics of how to combine them you can actually produce pretty sophisticated ML systems. A great resource for getting your head around them is [The Kernel Cookbook](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/duvenaud/cookbook/index.html) by David Duvenaud.

**RBF vs Squared Exponential:** This confuses a lot of people unnecessarily - they are the same thing! This common kernel is used all the time and goes by many names. However, call it a 'Squared Exponential' at your own risk as that is actually an inaccurate but commonly used term for it. Neil Lawrence, one of the many GP gods, says that we should stop calling it the 'Squared Exponential' kernel and rather the 'Exponentiated Quadratic' kernel.

Comment: updated [link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/index.html) to kernel cookbook

Comment: Link to my cookbook too hahah https://github.com/jkfitzsimons/IPyNotebook_MachineLearning/blob/master/Just%20Another%20Kernel%20Cookbook....ipynb